# How to install the scenario in ActiveRecord DadaProvider for each model

Tags: php, activerecord, orm, yii

How to install the scenario in yii ActiveRecord DadaProvider for **each** model;By default should update

```
public function afterFind()
{
   if ($this->scenario === 'searchView') {
            //myCode
   }
   parent::afterFind();
}
public function searchView()
{
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria([
            'select' => 'last_comment,name,data,cdate,mdate,edate,coperator,eoperator',
            'with' => ['houses', 'houses.city', 'houses.district', 'houses.street', 'stages']
        ]);
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, [
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => 'cdate DESC'
        ]);
}
```

Comment: If I understand well You want all your models retrieved by CActiveDataProvider to have the searchView scenario?

Comment: Yes! it is very important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can specify the scenario you want when fetching object the closest thing that I see is extending the `CActiveDataProvider` :

```
class CustomActiveDataProvider extends CActiveDataProvider {

    protected function fetchData()
    {
        $data = parent::fetchData();
        foreach($data as $model) {
            // do what you wanted to do in the afterFind
            // $model->afterFindSearchView()
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Then in your model you create the method `afterFindSearchView`, and when calling the data provider you do

```
return new CustomActiveDataProvider($this, [
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => 'cdate DESC'
]);
```

Comment: OMG! You helped me a lot, I am not able to do, doing the same thing, but did not call the method $model-> afterFind ()

Comment: You do not know why GridView return white screen ?

Comment: It's hard to know. In the log the sql query is executed as it should?

Comment: Completely blank screen, even no toolbar and html clean. Console error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: And if you put again the default data provider you still have the same error?

Comment: Yes, the same as if a lot of records can not give

Comment: You should ask a new question

Comment: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting ? I used CustomActiveDataProvider